# How to insert date in topNav

Tags: menus

In my theme i have a menu on the top of the page where i've links for my pages, this is the line of code in the **header.php** that generates topNav,

```
    <!-- BEGIN HEADER-TOP -->
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'topNav', 'depth' => 3, 'fallback_cb' => false, 'menu_class' => 'topNav')); ?>
    <!-- END HEADER-TOP -->
```

And this is the output of the above line,

```
<!-- BEGIN HEADER-TOP -->
<div class="menu-top-container">
<ul id="menu-top" class="topNav">
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/copyright-policy/">Copyright Policy</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/disclaimer/">Disclaimer</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
</ul></div>
<!-- END HEADER-TOP -->
```

What i want to do is to add date function on the right side of the menu, i don't know how to edit the above PHP code, i can do this manually by adding HTML code directly into the **header.php** but i have to do that every time just for adding a link. Please Guide me how can i add a div which holds the date function right after the `<ul>` tag ends.

Thanks

Comment: Please be specific: What exactly do you want to achieve? What have you tried already? What didn't work?

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) has a `$container` parameter that can be used to set the type of container (`div` or `nav`) or to disable it.

You could set the parameter to `false` and hardcode the wrapper `div` whilst including a date inside of it:

```
<!-- BEGIN HEADER-TOP -->
<div class="navigation-wrap">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'topNav',
        'depth' => 3,
        'fallback_cb' => false,
        'menu_class' => 'topNav',
        'container' => false
    )); ?>
    <div class="navigation-date">
        <?php echo date('l, jS \of F Y'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END HEADER-TOP -->
```